# Run Automator Workflow in background

Tags: applescript, ocr, automator, abbyy

Trying to make Automator workflow that uses "Convert to TXT Document" for pdf to txt convertion. But while running, Abbyy FineReader window becomes active. Is it possible to run in in silent mode or with minimized window?

Comment: @user3439894 I thought it could be done by some special keys or plist editing or smth. like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided not to use FineReader applet. Instead I migrate to stack: tesseract + ImageMagick + gs.
If anybody is interested, I attach my sollution below.

**Automator shell script**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

/usr/local/bin/convert -density 300 "$@" -depth 8 -strip -background white -alpha off image.tiff
/usr/local/bin/tesseract -l rus image.tiff ~/Desktop/OCR
rm image.tiff
```

And the 
**[Automator workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxvhW.png)**

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript works for me using the latest version of Sierra. Tested on my system, it did not bring Abbyy FineReader to the foreground.

```
set thePDF to (choose file)

tell application "FineReader"
    set resultFile to export to txt thePDF ¬
        from file thePDF
end tell
```

Your new text file should appear in the same directory as your original PDF

I'm not using Automator so I do not know which method you are going to use to pass the PDF file to this AppleScript.  For testing purposes, I used to the “choose file” command.  If you are using Automator to pass the PDF file that you specified in a previous Automator action, you can just remove the “choose file” command from the code.  Anyway, all you need to do is add a “run AppleScript” command in your Automator workflow.

If you are going to remove the “choose file” command, you'll need to re-define the value for the variable thePDF

[image]

---

**NOTE**  FineReader actually has an extensive AppleScript dictionary. My answer included a minimal version of many other options for the exporting as text.  Here is a full version example of options

```
tell application "FineReader"
    set resultFile to export to txt directParamFile ¬
        from file fromFileFile ¬
        ocr languages enum ocrLanguagesEnumLanguageListType ¬
        saving type savingTypeSaveSettingsEnum ¬
        retain layout retainLayoutTxtLayout ¬
        keep page numbers headers and footers keepPageNumbersHeadersAndFootersBoolean ¬
        keep line breaks and hyphenation keepLineBreaksAndHyphenationBoolean ¬
        insert page break character as page separator insertPageBreakCharacterAsPageSeparatorBoolean ¬
        use blank lines useBlankLinesBoolean ¬
        encoding encodingEncodingEnum
end tell
```

Comment: While with this method ABBYY FineReader is in the background, unfortunately its Dock Tile is incessantly bouncing the entire time and is quite annoying! Also the Convert to TXT Document action in Automator has many settings and these settings can be set as arguments to the `export to txt` _command_ in AppleScript, so you might want to make a note of that. If you don't have ABBYY FineReader, I can give you the blurb from the FineReader AppleScript Dictionary for it.

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C205) this script also opens the window of the FineReader (

Answer (score -2):

You could try this applescript in the script editor, replacing the file paths to your files. I don't have the program installed, so I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work, maybe it's something you can build on to get the result you're after.

```
tell application "FineReader" activate
tell application "System Events" set visible of process "FineReader" to false
tell application "FineReader"
   export to txt "/Path/to/filename/File_to_OCR.pdf" from file "/Path/to/filename/File_to_OCR.pdf"
end tell
```